# Можно ли обойти лимит отправки сообщений ВКонтакте?

Tags: vkontakte-api

В вк от бота можно отправлять только 20 сообщений в секунду. Долго думали как можно это обойти, думали делать много групп чтобы снизить время отправки.
Например, если рассылка 10К сообщений будет двадцати юзерам в секунду, то последний получит ответ с большой задержкой…
Да, есть в API метод, который рассылает сразу всем, но от группы можно отсылать только по 60 ответов в час, тобишь тоже не удобно. 
Как быть? Ответ "никак" - не устраивает, не отвечайте, если у вас такой ответ)

Спасибо

Comment: А что если на самом деле никак?

Comment: я же просил не писать... только время трачу

Comment: Тратить время на невозможное действительно глупо.

Comment: а что не глупо ? сидеть и оставлять проблему ? а вы молодец , так и делайте )))

Comment: жду нормальный ответов , а не из рода "никак"

Comment: «Хочу выключить гравитацию, как это сделать? Жду нормальных ответов, а не из рода "никак"»

Answer (score 0):

В одном messages.send можно передавать до 100 user_id, то есть 100 сообщений за вызов. 
Также в ВК есть метод execute: vk.com/dev/execute
Он позволяет делать до 25 запросов к API в одном вызове. То есть за один запрос к API можно отправить до 2500 сообщений. И таких запросов можно сделать 20 штук за секунду, то есть теоретический предел это 50000 сообщений в секунду.